# What are the pros and cons of adding specialty grains to the mash?

Tags: all-grain, steeping, mashing, specialty-grains

When all-grain brewing, you typically add all your grains to the mash, right?  Is there ever a time when you leave some of the specialty grains out and steep them instead?  What are the pros and cons of mashing everything versus leaving some grains out of the mash and steeping them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some specialty grains (e.g. dextrin/cara-pils) need to be mashed. These need to be mashed, because they require a chemical reaction to take place to be useful.

Some (e.g. crystal) need only to be steeped, but can also be put in the mash. These do not need a chemical reaction to take place to be useful, they just need to have the chemicals in them extracted into the wort (e.g., through steeping, then adding the "tea" into the wort). There is no benefit to steeping them when you're doing a mash anyway, the only reason they are steeped is if you're doing an extract brew (in which case you're not doing a mash -- steeping is less trouble). You steep the specialty malt instead of boiling it, because boiling it releases bitter tannins and other undesirable chemicals.

To sum up: if you're doing a mash, put the specialty grains in; there's no reason to steep them instead. If you're not doing a mash, steep them, because it's easier than mashing. This only works for the non-enzymatic specialty malts that don't require a mash.

Comment: Good answer.  But... Is there a mash chemistry benefit in steeping grains even if you're mashing?  When people get into all-grain, they're often advised to avoid messing with chemical adjustments - salts & acids - until they're comfortable with mashing.  If a young allgrainer wants to brew a stout with soft water, would it benefit him to steep the dark grains so as not to mess up mash chemistry?

Comment: @JackSmith - I can't say for sure, but I don't imagine the relatively small amounts of specialty grains would significantly affect mash chemistry.

Comment: but they do.  A stout is mostly base malt, but all the dark grains might mean you get a mash pH way too low.  http://www.howtobrew.com/section3/chapter15-3.html

Comment: @JackSmith: In my opinion, "How to Brew" is, in general, overly concerned with minor details that are unlikely to appreciably affect the quality of a beer. I tend to side with Papazian's "Relax. Don't worry. Have a homebrew." methodology.

Comment: So I brewed a stout this past weekend.  The recipe said SRM would be around 50 (I.e., really dark).  Based on my water report and Palmer's nomograph, I should be able to brew copper and amber beers without any water adjustment.  Theoretically, to brew a stout I'd need to boost alkalinity significantly to get the pH in range.  In practice, though, I found my mash pH to be 5.27 after 15 minutes with no chemical adjustments.  RDWHAHB indeed.

Comment: FWIW Crystal Malts are actually partially fermentable when mashed, more so with the lighter ones. So there is a difference between just steeping crystal vs mashing it. How much difference is up for debate, and it might not even be enough to be noticable. "Cold steeping" your dark roasted grains (Chocolate, Black Patent, etc) is regarded as a way to get less intense, smoother roast character, and is also recommended if your water isn't alkaline enough. As pointed out by others though, this might not ever be a problem for a lot of brewers.

Comment: See my longer response below for the reasoning behind my comment here: In short, if your water's pH is low to begin with, there is very good reason to keep darker grains out of your mash. If I don't do this I either have to add a lot of alkalinity via brewing salts or my beer will be destroyed. That said, my water is ridiculously low pH to begin with, and most people don't have to deal with that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I do sometimes leave some of the grains out of the mash and steep them separately.

Why? My water has a quite low pH to begin with, and adding too many dark grains during the mash can acidify the mash too much, forcing me to use Calcium Carbonate (Chalk) or Sodium Bicarbonate (Baking Soda) to bring the pH back up to the ideal mash range (~5.2 - 5.5 pH).

What is my rule of thumb?

Any grain that is 100 SRM or darker and does not need to be mashed gets steeped unless it's a very small percent of the grain bill (for a 5 gallon batch, I'll put as much as 4 oz in, but beyond that, I'm probably steeping).

Generally, that means Crystal/Caramel malts, Chocolate Malts, Roasted Barley, and other dark roasted malts.

The only reason you might consider steeping darker grains if your water's pH is fairly normal is that you can more carefully control the extraction of tannin/astringency from those dark grains by steeping for a shorter period of time or even cold steeping them overnight.

If you want more a more in-depth answer, here's an excerpt on my post about mashing sweet stout on [my website, Mad Alchemist](http://www.madalchemist.com/archives/mashing-the-perfect-sweet-stout/):

> Don’t mash your roasted-and-kilned grains (e.g. chocolate and black
>   malts). Roasted grains will drive the pH down considerably, so it’s
>   difficult to keep the pH high no matter what fancy solution you use
>   during the mash. Roasted grains have the wonderful benefit of not
>   needing to be mashed. So, the best solution, in my opinion, is to mash
>   everything except for your roasted grains in your MLT, and steep your
>   roasted grains in a separate vessel (below 170 F) simultaneously at
>   around 2 quarts per pound. Then, combine the wort created by the
>   roasted grains with the mashed wort in the brew kettle.
>
> If you don’t want to steep the grains, you can essentially brew a
>   coffee with the dark grains with either a more traditional method
>   (heat) or you can cold brew it overnight to really avoid the
>   astringency as much as possible… it’ll just take longer. If you cold
>   brew, you should probably bring the temperature of the concoction to
>   170 F after removing the grain to pasteurize it.
>
> Then, you can add the coffee-like brew whenever you want (start of the
>   boil, end of the boil, directly in the fermentation vessel, even just
>   before bottling). All will impart different character, so experiment!
>
> Note that you might not get full extraction from all roasted grains
>   when steeping. According to some experiments run by John Palmer, it
>   looks like Black Patent and Roasted Barley are some of the only
>   roasted malts that have the same yield as mashing when steeped. As
>   such, you might only exclude those from your sweet stout mash, or you
>   can increase the amount of other grains accordingly (e.g. multiply the
>   ounces of Chocolate Malt you use by ~1.5-1.6 to make up for the
>   difference).
>
> I would not recommend sparging with the roasted wort, in part because
>   you’re going to impact the sparge pH pretty significantly, and in part
>   because you’re going to leave some of your flavors behind.
>
> Hitting the ideal concentrations of all ions in the brewing water as
>   well as the ideal pH is very easy when you leave out your roasted
>   malts (and any other malts that don’t need to be mashed, such as
>   caramel/crystal). By steeping the roasted malts (and, optionally, your
>   crystal malts) separate from the mash, you might end up with a much
>   better sweet stout in the end. As someone commented, you could also
>   steep the grains in a bag while you transfer to the boil kettle from
>   your MLT, which sounds like a great idea.

Comment: +1. Very nice answer, Hop. I like the idea of avoiding the mashing problems entirely by using a separate steep for dark grains. I think I'll try to incorporate this into my brews. I had the dreaded "astringency" flavor in an early batch or two, and I suspect it was caused by a low pH in my mash.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason why you would ever need to do a separate steeping of grain.  You are basically steeping the grain in the mash.  Caramel malts are fully converted in the husks during the malting process and kilned with a moisture content of 50% which caramelizes the sugars inside, which means the sugars are ready to go.

So the pros to adding the specialty grain to the mash would be you don't need to do anything else and the cons would be that you would.

Answer (score 1):

The pro would be if your doing a split brew. I'm going to try a split brown and robust porter and eventually try a brown and a dry stout. So when doing a split brew I'm going to start with a brown. Split half into a carboy to ferment and then steep extra carafa/roast barley in the remainder to create the other half of the split. At least that's the plan.

Comment: I like this experiment/plan. Just be sure to fully boil any wort you steep with the roast barely to totally kill an lacto on the grain (ie, don't just cold steep the grain and pour the liquid directly into the carboy).